# ASP.NET Timeline control

Tags: asp.net, timeline

I have looked over other questions on this website, but am yet to find a solution that meets our requirements. 
We need a Timeline control that makes it possible to display some HR information (distribution of consultants) over longer periods of time (months). The screenshot below illustrates the requirement.

[image: Illustration]

We currently use a Windows-based component from a third party. We need this application to be visible on the **web**, including display on **iPad** devices. Are there any controls on the market that support this functionality?

Comment: Can't you just use a chart control with bars?

Comment: No, it's a timeline, not a bar chart.

Comment: I meant that couldn't the look you are trying to acheive be accomplished by using the built in ASP.NET charting control/bar charts

Comment: The screenshot is perhaps slightly misleading, each row can have multiple timeline bars and it's therefore not feasible to use bar charts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't explored many of the options yet, but I'm working on an application that uses DayPilot Lite (the open source version) from http://www.daypilot.org/ to display a calendar. The scheduler control looks like it could do something like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

maybe Telerik Scheduler

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/timelineview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: This one does not support a view for multiple months, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one from codeplex that might work...

http://timelinenet.codeplex.com/releases/view/11981

There's also the "viewer" approach you could take -- for example, you could put a view of Visio or MS Project, etc. in a window on your page.  Not sure how interactive it would be, but if your need is just for view-only, it might work.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/ASPNETVisioCustomControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?  Specifically you could, perhaps, use their [Annotated Timeline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

Google charts have some serious issues if any asp.net project is deployed in IIS.